# php curl can't connect after several request

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with my php curl. I am requesting to a url for like thousands times but after few hundred or thousands request. I am not able to connect to their server again because of that I can't complete the loop of my requests. does any one encounter the same problem? here is the error I have: Couldn't connect to server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely their firewall blocking you due to the fact that you're sending too many requests, this is called **rate limiting**. You will either have to contact them regarding this or find a way of reducing the requests you send.

You don't really have any way of knowing how the server rate limits requests, but I would suggest waiting a second or two between requests and try not to send too many requests at once.

Comment: You are right, I just contacted them and they have a limit of 34 request per second.